# Put all tables inside a div and put the div in middle with vertical scroll based on a set height

Tags: html, css

I have a sample html here.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table id = "tbl_cusname" name = "tbl_cusname" class = "mytable" width = "300px" style="float: left">
        ...
        <table id = "tbl_drnumber" name = "tbl_drnumber" class = "mytable" width = "60px" style="float: left">
        ...

        and other tables
    </div>
</body>
```

that as far as i know is all of my tables are encapsulated on the div.
I wonder how can i do the following?

- Center it not the content but the div together with its content
- Set height on it then put vertical scroll bar in case theres a overflow

tysm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `margin: 0 auto` way and add `max-height` to set a max height for the div then you can scroll, check the snippet below:

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

To center the div, set width and margin like this:

```
.yourDivSelector{
    width: 970px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

To set the height, use min-height like this:

```
min-height: 100%;
```

For vertical scroll set:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 1):

**I hope this is what you have in mind -**

For making the `div` centre I have used:

```
width: 70%;
margin: 20px auto;
```

> 20px just to give some space on top and bottom.

For making the `div` scroll on the overflow of content I have used:

```
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

> You can play with 200px as per your need.

A working sample for you.

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <table id="tbl_cusname" name="tbl_cusname" class="mytable" width="300px" style="float: left">
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tbl_drnumber" name="tbl_drnumber" class="mytable" width="60px" style="float: left">
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tbl_drnumber" name="tbl_drnumber" class="mytable" width="60px" style="float: left">
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
        <td>Hi am sample text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for something like below snippet!

1. Add `height` and `overflow` to `div.tableContainer`
2. set `margin: 0 auto` to tables inside container

```css
.tableContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tableContainer table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tableContainer">
    <table id="tbl_cusname" name="tbl_cusname" class="mytable" width="300px" border="1">
      <thead>
        <th>Head</th>
        <th>Head</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="tbl_drnumber" name="tbl_drnumber" class="mytable" width="60px" border="1">
      <thead>
        <th>Head</th>
        <th>Head</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Content</td>
          <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```